# How to test read-write lock using JUnit?

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, thread-safety

I have two methods, one for reading and one for writing. They both access the same collection and are used across multiple threads. For example, three threads for writing and eight - for reading. I need to test the thread safety of my collection. The write method takes precedence.

```java
public static void insertEntity(Entity entity) {
        try {
            readWriteLock.writeLock().lock();

            Session session = sf.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();

            GenericDAO.insertEntity(session, entity);

            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();
        } finally {
            readWriteLock.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }


public static Entity getByID(Integer id) {
        try {
            readWriteLock.readLock().lock();

            Session session = sf.openSession();
            Entity entity = GenericDAO.selectByID(session, Entity.class, id);

            session.close();
            return entity;
        } finally {
            readWriteLock.readLock().unlock();
        }

    }
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question. If locks are applied correctly, there is no need to test the thread-safety *itself*.
Let's ake some assumptions about `readWriteLock`: (a) it is only used by these two methods (or also correct in other places) and (b) it is not used *inside* any of the methods invoked between the `try` and `finally`. 
 
In that case, you can rely on the locks doing the work for you in a correct manner.

Comment: @Emmef I understand you. But how can I be shure that I use `readWriteLock` correctly if I cannot test my methods? It is like using `for i` cycle with i < 1000` condition for every array even if it does not have length bigger or equal then 1000. Do I need to trust to my programmer skills that I can write code and improve it without errors? Sorry for the bad analogy

Comment: If you meet the conditions (a) and (b) in my  earlier comment, I can tell you that the shown usage of the locks is correct, which can also be verified in their documentation. Other than that, testing multi-threaded code is often a complex, unreliable manner. It forces you to make intrusive changes to your code that you would not want in the production code. For example inserting lines with [countdown latches](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html), and tactical calls to `await()` and `countDown()` in different threads. Hard; not always a guarantee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test your lock handling, you should extract that logic in to its own class.
What has to be done while holding the lock should be encapsulated into an interface.
Your production code implementation will do the Entity stuff. Your test code implementation will stress the lock handling (e.g. asserting mutual exclusivity)

By the way: your locking code is not correct. You should `unlock()` a lock only if the corresponding `lock()` succeeded. The pattern goes like this:

```
lock.lock();
try {
    // do stuff
} finally {
    lock.unlock();
}
```